# Do ちょうだい、ごらん、ください、おいで constitute an own class of part of speech?

Tags: grammar

They are all used after the Te-Form of Japanese verbs similar to subsidiary verbs, but they seem to differ from subsidiary verbs. What is their true nature?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think they seem to differ from subsidiary verbs?

Comment: At least ご覧 and 頂戴 are not verbs and they're used without する as in 来て頂戴 or 考えてごらん, although you can use ごらんなさい. As @Ookami mentioned, Japanese dictionaries call it 「補助動詞の命令形**のように**使って」. The 日本国語大辞典 calls it an abbreviation of 頂戴つかまつる, but irregardless of its etymology it might or might not have become grammaticalized.

Answer (score 7):

**No, they do not constitute their own class of part of speech**.  It is true, however, that they can function in such an "exceptional" way that it makes them look as though they constituted one of their own.

> 「ちょうだい」 is a **noun** by name (頂戴 in kanji), meaning "the **humble** act of receiving something".

**Usage as a straight-up noun:**

「おいしいハムを頂戴しました。」 = "I have (humbly) received some tasty ham."

**Subsidiary verb-like usage:**

Though it is a noun, 「ちょうだい」 can be attached to the [連用形]{れんようけい} of a verb to express roughly what the word "please" does in English.  This would usually be more like a friendly request than an "imperative".

「たまには[電話]{でんわ}してちょうだい。」 = "Please call me once in a while."

**Verb-like usage:**

「ちょうだい」 can also function like a verb on its own without a "real" verb right in front of it.  When used this way, it can only mean "Give me ~~".

「それ（を）ちょうだい。」 = "Gimme that!"

> 「ごらん」 is also a **noun** by category as one could tell from the honorific 「ご」 -- 「ご[覧]{らん}」 -- meaning "(your highly respectable) act of seeing".  It is an honorific (respectful) form of 「[見]{み}ること」.

**Usage as a straight-up noun:**

「ご覧のとおりです。」 = "It's just as you can see."

**Subsidiary verb-like usage as the shortened form of 「ごらんなさい」:**

「[来]{き}てごらん。[手品]{てじな}をみせてあげる。」 = "Come over here; I'll show you a magic trick."

**Verb-like usage:**

「ごらん！」 = "Take a look!"

> 「ください」 is both a **verb** and a **subsidiary verb**.

**As a verb:**

As a verb, it is the imperative form of 「[下]{くだ}さる」.　　「下さる」 is the honorific form of 「[与]{あた}える」 and 「くれる」, both of which mean "to give".

「ビッグマックをふたつ下さい。」 = "Please give me two Big Macs."

「これがスミスさんの下さった[時計]{とけい}です。」 = "This is the clock that Mr. Smith has given me."

**As a subsidiary verb:**

Attach it directly to the 連用形 of a verb and you will have a '(Verb), please!' structure.  Careful writers will write ください for this usage in kana: It is the official rule, too.

「3[時頃]{じごろ}に[来]{き}てください。」 = "Please come around 3 o'clock."

「ボクと[結婚]{けっこん}してください。」 = "Please marry me!"

> 「おいで」 is probably the most complicated of the four words but I will make my explanation as concise as possible.  It is both a **noun** and a **compound word**.  Notice the honorific 「お」 once again.

**As a noun:**

おいで is a respectful word for "coming", "going" and "staying".  I told you it was complicated.

「田中さんがおいでです。」  = "Mr. Tanaka is here." (He has just arrived.)

「どちらへおいでですか。」 = "Where might you be going?"

**As a compound:**

Forms an **honorific** phrase (again, for coming, going and staying) when followed by 「になる」、「くださる」, etc.

「[来週]{らいしゅう}おいでくださいますか。」 = "Would you please come next week?"

「いつも[夜]{よる}はご[自宅]{じたく}においでになりますか。」 = "Are you usually at home at night time?"

**Quasi-verb-like usage (for a lack of word):**

「ここへおいで。」 = "Come over here."

「[雨]{あめ}が[止]{や}むまでここにおいで。」 = "Why dontcha stay here until the rain lets up."

**Subsidiary verb-like usage**

Attached to a real verb, おいで can function like a subsidiary verb to form a friendly and honorific request.

「もうお[店]{みせ}も[閉]{し}まってるから、うちでご[飯]{はん}を[食]{た}べておいで。」

= "Since stores should be closed by now, please eat dinner with us here (before you go home)."

Answer (score 1):

- in the ちょうだい（頂戴） you have a familiar relationship, like a mother talking to a child:

  > 座って頂戴/静かにして頂戴.

  In those case this form is close to the 命令形. [See 大辞林.](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A0%82%E6%88%B4-328222)
- in ごらん（ご覧） is a polite form for -teminasai (～てみなさい) that is also a 命令形.

  > 座ってご覧/静かにしてご覧.

  [See 大辞泉.](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E8%A6%A7-269996#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)
- in ください（下さい） is a polite way to ask someone (a teacher, a boss, older person, any one superior to you) to do something.

  > 座ってください/静かにしてください.
- in おいで（御出で） can be use in a similar way as in ちょうだい but in this case you're not asking, you're giving an instruction.

  > 座っておいで/静かにしておいで.

Comment: It seemed to me like the OP already knew their meaning and was asking about their syntactic status in the language...